# I'm having trouble scanning hex values into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am trying to scan a .dat file containing hex values into an array using fscanf(). My program successfully scans the file and puts values into the array, but when I print them back out to console, the values are drastically different. The following code is my function that opens the file and scans it. I'm using a test.txt file right now that has the values "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f" in it. When I run the program what prints in the console is 5 hex values that change after each run followed by "0 ffffffff 0 0 0".

```
void sim(int bytes, int lines, int sets, int policy){
    int i = 0;
    int total_Misses = 0;
    int total_References = 0;
    FILE *f1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (f1 == NULL){
        printf("File failed to open");
        exit(0);
    }
    unsigned int a[10];

    while (i < 10){

        fscanf(f1, "%x", &a[i]);
        printf("%x ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your file look like? Are there actually 10 values in there? Check the result of `fscanf`.

Comment: How did you create this `test.txt` file? If you used a plain text editor, make sure it hasn't added a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. Try typing `xxd test.txt` at the command line and see what it looks like.

Comment: Best test if `fscanf` correctly returns `1` before assuming it prints a 'wrong' value.

Comment: You should open the text file in a hex editor to verify your source is sane.

Comment: Definitely follow up withsqueamish ossifrage and  [@Rad Lexus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166801/im-having-trouble-scanning-hex-values-into-an-array-in-c#comment59971032_36166801) good ideas.  Up vote for a well presented 1st question.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK and all comments point to a problem with the input. I suggest you adapt the code to the following to catch errors:

```
while (i < 10){

    if (fscanf(f1, "%x", &a[i])==1) {
        printf("%x ", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    else printf ("Error reading field %d\n", i);
}
```

P.s.: `a[10]` is an automatic variable and not initialized. Hence not reading a value for the array entry will print the uninitialzed garbage value you are experiencing.

P.p.s.: I often see `scanf` gurus add a space before the `%` sign to skip leading white space.